# Michaelis Menten kinetics - Plotting to find V-max and Km

Tags: enzymes, enzyme-kinetics

In dealing with the question above I know that if we plot 1/v against 1/[isocitrate] we can get V-max = 1/intercept and Km = slope/intercept.

However when I express the two rows of values in micromoles I get intercept = 3359, and I believe it will be in micromoles? That gives me V-max = 1/(3359*10^-6) = 297.7. However, how do I know the order of magnitude of this number? The textbook says it is pmol, but how is it picomoles/ dm3 s? [image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about Biology but numerical manipulation, and in a specific instance. There are many resources on the web for this sort of thing.

Comment: Another more general point. Do not post text as images. It discriminates against people with sight disabilities.

Answer (score 1):

The order of magnitude for your intercept value depends on the axis of your graph, which in turn depends on the values / units of your input values.

As an example if your substrate concentrations are in the range of $\mu mol / l$ (which is micro*molar*, not mircomoles), then that is also the order of magnitue you'll get out of the calculation.

$dm^{-3}$ equals litre's ($1dm^{-3} = 1l$), it's not usually not used for concentartions, so I can't say why the textbook used it instead. Maybe they wanted to use base SI units.